# What version of support library is installed in my Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-library

I tried to add a `CardView` in my app so I added the following dependency in my gradle

`compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:22.2.1'`

I realised that an error is caused because I have given the wrong version number. After taking a look at the official google docs I came to know that `Android Support Repository` is used to hold `appcompat` libraries.
[image]

As you can see the Support repository that I have installed is version 33. But if I change my gradle to version 33 it is still showing error.

How can I check what version of AppCompatLibrary I have in android studio?

EDIT:

`build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.spintum.preexam"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    //    compile fileTree (dir:'libs',include:'achartengine-*.jar')
    //compile fileTree('libs/achartengine-1.1.0.jar')
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
    //compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.+'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.markushi:circlebutton:1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.ToxicBakery.viewpager.transforms:view-pager-transforms:1.2.32@aar'
}
```

Comment: 33 is not correct... Should be 23.  https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html#v7

Answer (score 16):

Check your SDK folder and see which is the highest existing number:

e.g
B:\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\appcompat-v7

There will be a folder for each installed version. At the time of writing, 24 is the latest version.

**Update:**

Now Google use their own Maven repository, this no longer works.
Instead, check this site for the available versions.

https://maven.google.com/

Comment: It works fine on my emulator (Marshmallow) but it crashes in my device (KitKat).. Any Idea why that is happening?

Comment: Grade controls your build. If you are crashing, the problem is most likely your code. I would recommend you open a new question and post your crash log.

Comment: sweet clyde, this needs to be better documented

Answer (score 6):

It is not about the installed version of the Android Support Repository.

The version that should be in the Gradle Build Files should be the number highest version corresponding to your

> `compileSdkVersion`

in your AppLevel Gradle Build File.(by default it is the **app module**).

***Example:***

If you are using ***compileSdkVersion 23*** , then you should check your following directory for the highest 23.x.x folder.

> \ **YOUR-SDK-PATH**
>   \extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\cardview-v7

Suppose that your highest number starting from 23 is 23.4.0 , then you should use this version number(**23.4.0 replacing the 33.0.0**) for your Gradle Build File(Not the verison of Android Support Repository Installed).

***It means you have to use the Android Support Repository Libraries according to your compileSdkVersion.***

Comment: I checked and my compileSdkVersion is 22 and the highest library I have is `22.2.1` and unfortunately it is not working. Any other suggestions??

Comment: It works fine on my emulator (Marshmallow) but it crashes in my device (KitKat).. Any Idea why that is happening?

Comment: It says an error occurred in the chart that I have created but if I remove the `cardview `elements and dependencies then no error is shown and the app runs correctly. If I add the dependencies then the app crashes in my kitkat device

Answer (score 2):

The easist way is to use `+` which means the newest one (of the API level) on your machine, then you do not need to check the SDK folder anymore. e.g.,

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
```

However, there is an warning `void using 21.+ ...."`.

Comment: Hmm... if there is a warning, probably not the best way though.